# Agrupar por existencia de valor en columna

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buen día, como puedo lograr agrupar varias filas mediante un campo que es el mismo (DNI) donde se evalúe si existe un registro ya sea en `[Dosis1_FechaVacunacion]`,`[Dosis2_FechaVacunacion]` o `[Dosis3_FechaVacunacion]`, por ejemplo si una persona (DNI) se le aplicó hasta `[Dosis2_FechaVacunacion]` que considere los valores de esa fila como principales para que se agrupen en una.

Adjunto la consulta y el resultado.:

```
SELECT  [DISA],[RED],[MICRORED],[CODIGO],[ESTABLECIMIENTO],CODCOLEGIO,NOMBRECOLEGIO,[DNI],[UBIGEO],[PROCEDENCIA],[FENACIMIENTO]
    ,MAX([EDAD]) AS EDAD
    ,MAX(LOTE) AS LOTE
    ,Max([Dosis1_FechaVacunacion]) as FechaDosis_1
    ,Max([Dosis2_FechaVacunacion]) as FechaDosis_2
    ,Max([Dosis3_FechaVacunacion]) as FechaDosis_3
 FROM [Pruebas].[dbo].[VPHMILAGROS]
 WHERE DNI='60039359'
 group by [DISA],[RED],[MICRORED],[CODIGO],[ESTABLECIMIENTO],CODCOLEGIO,NOMBRECOLEGIO,[DNI],[UBIGEO], [PROCEDENCIA],[FENACIMIENTO]
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero lograr es lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que te encuentras es que tienes valores distintos en campos como `RED`, `MICRORED`, `CODIGO`, etc. Eso hace que al realizar el `GROUP BY` no se agregue como tu deseas.

La solución para por quedarte con un solo dato de ellos, o bien concatenarlos. Para ello puedes utilizar subconsultas. Por ejemplo

```
SELECT MAX([DISA]) as DISA, MAX([RED]) as RED, MAX([MICRORED]) as MICRORED,MAX([CODIGO])
, MAX([ESTABLECIMIENTO]) as ESTABLECIMIENTO, MAX(CODCOLEGIO) as CODCOLEGIO, MAX(NOMBRECOLEGIO) as NOMBRECOLEGIO 
, a.[DNI], MAX([UBIGEO]) as UBIGEO, MAX([PROCEDENCIA]) as PROCEDENCIA, MAX([FENACIMIENTO]) as FENACIMIENTO
, MAX(b.EDAD) as EDAD, MAX(LOTE) AS LOTE
, MAX(b.FechaDosis_1) as FechaDosis_1, MAX(b.FechaDosis_2) as FechaDosis_2, MAX(b.FechaDosis_3) as FechaDosis_3
FROM [Pruebas].[dbo].[VPHMILAGROS] a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DNI, MAX([EDAD]) AS EDAD
    ,Max([Dosis1_FechaVacunacion]) as FechaDosis_1
    ,Max([Dosis2_FechaVacunacion]) as FechaDosis_2
    ,Max([Dosis3_FechaVacunacion]) as FechaDosis_3
    FROM [Pruebas].[dbo].[VPHMILAGROS]
    WHERE DNI='60039359'
    GROUP BY DNI
) b on a.DNI = b.DNI
GROUP BY a.DNI
```

Otra opción es concatenar los valores que se repiten por filas, entonces en vez de un `MAX` en el que perdemos información, obtendremos una lista separada por comas con la función `STRING_AGG`.

```
SELECT STRING_AGG([DISA],',') as DISA, STRING_AGG([RED],',') as RED, STRING_AGG([MICRORED], ',') as MICRORED, STRING_AGG([CODIGO], ',')
, STRING_AGG([ESTABLECIMIENTO], ',') as ESTABLECIMIENTO, STRING_AGG(CODCOLEGIO, ',') as CODCOLEGIO, STRING_AGG(NOMBRECOLEGIO, ',') as NOMBRECOLEGIO 
, a.[DNI], STRING_AGG([UBIGEO], ',') as UBIGEO, STRING_AGG([PROCEDENCIA], ',') as PROCEDENCIA, STRING_AGG([FENACIMIENTO], ',') as FENACIMIENTO
, STRING_AGG(b.EDAD, ',') as EDAD, STRING_AGG(LOTE, ',') AS LOTE
, MAX(b.FechaDosis_1) as FechaDosis_1, MAX(b.FechaDosis_2) as FechaDosis_2, MAX(b.FechaDosis_3) as FechaDosis_3
FROM [Pruebas].[dbo].[VPHMILAGROS] a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DNI
    ,Max([Dosis1_FechaVacunacion]) as FechaDosis_1
    ,Max([Dosis2_FechaVacunacion]) as FechaDosis_2
    ,Max([Dosis3_FechaVacunacion]) as FechaDosis_3
    FROM [Pruebas].[dbo].[VPHMILAGROS]
    WHERE DNI='60039359'
    GROUP BY DNI
) b on a.DNI = b.DNI
GROUP BY a.DNI
```

Puede que haya exagerado haciendo un `MAX` o un `STRING_AGG` en todos los campos, tu sabrás la composición de los datos y cuales pueden repetirse y cuales no.

La idea es que la primera consulta solo aparezca una línea por DNI, y la unamos (con el `INNER JOIN`) a la segunda que también solo contendrá una solo línea por DNI.